# Jenkins master (built-in) node high CPU usage

Tags: jenkins

We have a Jenkins server (2.319.2-lts-alpine) running in a docker container in an AWS EC2 c5.2xlarge instance, which has 8 vCPUs.
This Jenkins server has a master (now called built-in) node which has #0 executors set because we don't want to run any builds there. It is used only for assigning builds in the queue to the respective slave nodes by the label.

Now, this built-in node is constantly showing 100% CPU percentage in JavaMelody monitoring, causing Jenkins to be slow at times to respond. We end up having a lot of 504 timeouts during the day.

[image: JavaMelody Monitoring]

These are the JVM options we have set for the built-in node: `"-XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=60.0 -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50.0 -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true -Dmail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dhudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer.EXCLUDE_SESSION_ID=true -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.CLIENT_TIMEOUT=300 -Xloggc:$JENKINS_HOME/gc-%t.log -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:GCLogFileSize=20m -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCCause -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:G1SummarizeRSetStatsPeriod=1 -Djenkins.CLI.disabled=true -Dpermissive-script-security.enabled=no_security -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0 -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/jenkins/logging.properties"`

This is what we get running "htop":
[image: htop output]

I notice that even though the CPU percentage sometimes decreases, it doesn't decrease that much and immediately rises to 100% if any job gets in the queue.

I already spent a lot of time googling to try to find anything that works, but I cannot find the reason why the CPU is always so high on usage.
Any idea to help me figure this out?

Comment: Probably you will have to take a thread dump and analyze this further.

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing a very similar issue, with almost the same setup. Our Jenkins built-in also has 0 executors, but even so it takes some finite resources for it to provision the agent to run the job. We are finding that our CPU is throttled to the point where even that provisioning step (which includes a git checkout for jenkins-shared-library) will stall, causing more jobs to pile-up at the same step.

We've tried a few things, such as:

- Cleaning up old jobs
- Cleaning up un-needed fingerprints

Which did seem to help us get below the throttling threshold for a while, but it always creeps back up and we get stuck in the same situation.

I would definitely suggest those two cleanups to start, and take a look at your job retention to see if you are holding onto jobs you don't need.

Overall though, still looking for a better solution...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So we found out that this problem was caused by the Prometheus metrics plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/prometheus/).

prometheus_async_worker thread (**look at the Cpu time!!**):

[image]

Before removing the plugin and no builds running (100% System CPU all the time):

[image]

After removing the plugin:

[image]

As a temporary measure, since we don't know what is causing the plugin to behave like this and we don't know how to fix it, we removed this plugin from Jenkins.

We will install the plugin again as soon as a new version comes out and check how Jenkins behaves.